# Codeigniter3 cannot find MY_Controller using composer autoloader

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using the composer autoloader in CI3, it's the default folder layout for composer with vendor in the root folder so I set it up in the config like so:

```
$config['composer_autoload'] = __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/autoload.php';
```

This works fine I can load composer packages into the controller classes fine. I want to create a new 'base' controller which all my controllers extend but no matter what I try I get the error `Fatal error: Class 'MY_Controller' not found`.

MY_Controller.php (core/MY_Controller.php)

```
<?php

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Welcome.php (application/controllers/Welcome.php)

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');


class Welcome extends MY_Controller {

    public function __construct() 
    {
       parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
}
```

Loading this view then gives me the error `Fatal error: Class 'MY_Controller' not found`. I'm guessing its the fact I'm using the composer autoloader instead of the CI default one?

I've seen all sorts of crazy and "creative?" solutions to get this working using __autoload() in the config file? But none of them seem to work at all. Has anyone had this issue before?

Comment: Do you have this line  `$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';` set in `application/config/config.php`?

Comment: Yeah @JamesWalker everything else is default out of the box CI 3.1.3 the only change is to use the composer autoloader rather than the CI "autoloader" which is actually just eager-loading

Comment: I've never had a problem with composer, but I use the 'stock' /application/vendor/ location by setting `$config['composer_autoload']=TRUE`. Is MY_Controller.php in /application/core?

Comment: @ourmandave /application/vendor/ is not the stock folder? There is nothing in the JSON file to tell composer to use a different location so composer puts the vendor folder in the root of the project, not the /application/vendor/ that CI has in its config. CI seems confused, its config by default says /application/vendor/ but its package.json puts it in the root /vendor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My_Controller should be on application/core/MY_Controller.php
Also check for $config['subclass_prefix'] value should be 'MY_' like James Walker said

Comment: I mean, He said its on core/MY_Controller.php, I said it should be on application/core/MY_Controller.php then